# How do I assign a value in JSON that becomes an enum string value in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to add sample data for my unit tests and I'm getting an assignment error when I'm trying to read in the JSON file related to the enum assignment.

types.ts

```
export enum TestType {
    TYPE1 = "type1",
    TYPE2 = "type2",
    TYPE3 = "type 3"
}

export interface SampleDataType {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    dataType?: TestType;
}
```

exampleData.json

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "first",
        "dataType": "type1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "second",
        "dataType": "type2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "third",
        "dataType": "type3"
    }
]
```

unitTest.ts

```
import * as exampleData from "../../components/__mocks__/test-data/exampleData.json";
//...
const testItems: SampleDataType[] = exampleData;
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I've also tried using "TYPE1" as the sample data value, but  no luck. Is there a way to assign the value in json and have it read in the unit test?

Comment: Where at? In the JSON file?

Comment: Interestingly, I get exampleData.map is not a function.   
`const testItems: SampleDataType[] = exampleData.map(item => ({...item, dataType: item.dataType as TestType}));`

Comment: I fixed the .map is not a function issue by changing the import from import * as exampleData to just import exampleData. Your solution does work, but it feels a bit hacky. If there isn't a way to define it directly in the JSON I'll accept that as the answer. I'll also upvote it if you write that as one of the answers.

Comment: @rid the solution is also a bit messy when I have enums nested deeper down in the object.